# Substitute textjoin formula not working for final cell

Tags: excel, unique, substitution, excel-2016, textjoin

I'm trying to remove the unique values after joining cells in Excel. It's a list of phone numbers that I combine into a single cell after I separate them with a comma. I'm using this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,$I$19:$I$28),I19&",","")
```

For whatever reason, it properly applies to every cell in the range except for the last one; meaning that the last phone number still shows up in the final list. So for example, if I have numbers `12345 23456 34567 and 45678`, it should come out like this:

```
23456,34567,45678    
12345,34567,45678    
12345,23456,45678    
12345,23456,34567
```

but it comes out like this

```
23456,34567,45678    
12345,34567,45678    
12345,23456,45678    
12345,23456,34567,45678
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

It is looking for `45678,` to substitute with `""`.  There is no `,` at the end.  So we force one and then remove it at the end:

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,$I$19:$I$28) & ",",I19&",",""),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,$I$19:$I$28) & ",",I19&",",""))-1)
```

Or put the comma on the front and use MID:

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,$I$19:$I$28),"," &I19,""),2,999)
```

Or you can use TEXTJOIN in an array form:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF((ROW($I$19:$I$28)<>ROW(19:19))*($I$19:$I$28<>""),$I$19:$I$28,""))
```

Being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Then copy/drag it down like you do with the first.

---

The second, using the MID is the better of the choices.

Comment: @user8529169 Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.